# Adding a number thats constant within participants but differs between participants (lv. 2 variable) [loop r, MLM]

Tags: r, loops, data-cleaning, multilevel-analysis

I want to calculate a moderation analysis in a multilevel model. I have 20 taskblocks (lvl 1) for 33 participants (lvl 2). For my relevant IV and DV I have already written a loop that works:

```
for(i in 1:length(participants)) {
  participant.sub <- df[df$participant == participants[i],]
  participant.sub <- participant.sub[!is.na(participant.sub$participant),]
  for (j in 1:20) {
    block.sub <- participant.sub[participant.sub$block == j,]
    data.row <- c(unique(block.sub$participant),
                  j,
                  block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response)],
                  block.sub$goal[!is.na(block.sub$goal)],
                  block.sub$sum_correct[!is.na(block.sub$sum_correct)])
    data.row <- data.row[2:6]
    dummy.df <- rbind(dummy.df, data.row) 
  }
}
```

Now I want to include the moderators. The moderator variables are likert-scales that got answered before the experiment started. Each person has exactly one value on each scale. How do I add those values to the current loop/data frame, so that I can continue with lmer?

I tried this

```
for(i in 1:length(participants)) {
  participant.sub <- df[df$participant == participants[i],]
  participant.sub <- participant.sub[!is.na(participant.sub$participant),]
  for (j in 1:20) {
    block.sub <- participant.sub[participant.sub$block == j,]
    data.row <- c(unique(block.sub$participant),
                  j,
                  block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response)],
                  block.sub$goal[!is.na(block.sub$goal)],
                  block.sub$sum_correct[!is.na(block.sub$sum_correct)],
                  block.sub$slider_effort.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_effort.response)],
                  block.sub$slider_talent.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_talent.response)],
                  block.sub$slider_luck.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_luck.response)],
                  block.sub$slider_taskdiff.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_taskdiff.response)])
    data.row <- data.row[2:9] 
    dummy.df <- rbind(dummy.df, data.row) 
  }
}
```

and

```
for(i in 1:length(participants)) {
  participant.sub <- df[df$participant == participants[i],]
  participant.sub <- participant.sub[!is.na(participant.sub$participant),]
  for (j in 1:20) {
    block.sub <- participant.sub[participant.sub$block == j,]
    data.row <- c(unique(block.sub$participant),
                  j,
                  block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response[!is.na(block.sub$slider_mentaleffort.response)],
                  block.sub$goal[!is.na(block.sub$goal)],
                  block.sub$sum_correct[!is.na(block.sub$sum_correct)],
                  block.sub$slider_effort.response,
                  block.sub$slider_talent.response,
                  block.sub$slider_luck.response,
                  block.sub$slider_taskdiff.response)
    data.row <- data.row[2:9] 
    dummy.df <- rbind(dummy.df, data.row) 
  }
}
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Hi Himang Choi, welcome to SO. It will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). So run `dput()` on all the data you are using e.g. `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df),n)` if the datasets are large (where n is the minimum number of rows to allow us to replicate your loops). Then, copy the results into a codeblock in your question. Also, it is _highly likely_ your desired output can be achieved without using a loop. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! As you have said, I was able to solve it much more elegantly by selecting columns and merging them! The solution through a loop was rather out of helplessness than anything. >-<

For future questions I will take note and add a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Please do post your solution as an answer. Self-answering is very much encouraged on SO. You can also self-accept your own answer. But as you acknowledge, it would make it much more useful to people in the future (and more likely to attract upvotes :) ) if it's an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use dpylr and slice the data in the rows I wanted, before merging them into one frame, that leaves out the na's

```
df_attitude <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(slider_talent.response)) %>%
  select(participant, slider_talent.response, slider_luck.response, slider_effort.response, slider_taskdiff.response)
data <- data %>%
  merge(., df_attitude, by = "participant")

df_effort <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(slider_mentaleffort.response)) %>%
  select(participant, block, slider_mentaleffort.response, sum_correct)
df_goal <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(goal)) %>%
  select(participant, block, goal)
```

It is the more elegant, flexible and shorter way than looping.